# What does "bindings" middleware do in Laravel 5.6?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, middleware, laravel-middleware

Just as per the title. Default api middleware in Laravel 5.6 is listed in `Kernel.php` as:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
];
```

I'd appreciate a layman's explanation of what `bindings` does, which I can't find anywhere.

It uses the `SubstituteBindings` class which has the `handle` method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $this->router->substituteBindings($route = $request->route());
    $this->router->substituteImplicitBindings($route);
    return $next($request);
}
```

Though I still don't follow what it does.

Comment: I started reading that after posting the question- thanks. But I'm still unclear how this relates to the binding Middleware which that short section of the docs doesn't mention. Do I have to pass all routes through this middleware before I can use Route Model Binding? That section of the docs seems to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same question, and was able to find this:

> "`Route model binding` is now accomplished using middleware. All
>   applications should add the
>   Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings to your web
>   middleware group in your app/Http/Kernel.php file:
>
> \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
>
> You should also register a route middleware for binding substitution
>   in the $routeMiddleware property of your HTTP kernel:
>
> 'bindings' =>
>   \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class, ..."

which can be found on this page - https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade

The above answer was originally from this source - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47784205/3089840

So it sounds to me like the `bindings` middleware is just a shortcut term for `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` - If this is correct, I'm not sure why Laravel doesn't use the same terminology in both the `web` and the `api` arrays in `Kernel.php`.  It seems kind of inconsistent and confusing to use `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class` in the `web` array and `bindings` in the `api` array.

Answer (score 10):

I think the thing that you're asking for is this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-model-binding

```php
Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
    return $user->email;
});
```

It binds the User model right away.